# Python wrap/format a list when printed

Tags: python, list, formatting, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, I have a list  containing strings of numbers 1-25 (for example). When printing them, I want the list to print on 5 lines, with 5 numbers per line.

Ideally:

```
>>> print(myList)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
 '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
 ...
 ...
 '21', '22', '23', '24', '25']
```

I know if I have to I can simply make five separate lists within myList and call

```
print(myList[0])
print(myList[1])
...
```

but I would really like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to roll your own representation function, like

```
def wrap_list(items, items_per_line=5):
    items = list(items)
    lines = []
    for i in range(0, len(items), items_per_line):
        chunk = items[i:i + items_per_line]
        line = ", ".join(map(repr, chunk))
        lines.append(line)
    return "[{}]".format(",\n ".join(lines))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> print(wrap_list(map(str, range(25))))
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
 '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
 '10', '11', '12', '13', '14',
 '15', '16', '17', '18', '19',
 '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 8 seconds... *mumble grumble*

Answer (score 3):

The Python standard library provides [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html):

```py
import textwrap as _tw


values = list(map(
    str, range(25)))
wrapped = _tw.fill(
    str(values), 
    width=20)
print(wrapped)
```

Comment: Good idea to look into the stdlib, but this doesn't really do what the OP is trying to do - outputting five *items* of the list per row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a no-frills solution that uses a for-loop:

```
for n, val in enumerate(myList, 1):
    print val,
    if n % 5 == 0:
        print "\n"
if n % 5:
    print "\n" # end the last line, if any
```

The enumeration starts at 1 to avoid a stray newline at the start.

Comment: This does not print the leading [ nor trailing ], nor does it indent the all of the lines except the first. But nice use of enumerate with starting value

Comment: Adding the brackets and indent is kind of trivial, isn't it? I just demonstrated the line-wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any ready-to-use function for this purpose, you probably still need to split the original list, or write your own print function. There is a simple solution by splitting the original list:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint([l[i:i+5] for i in xrange(0, len(l), 5)])
```

However, it only works with the lists whose length are times by 5 (or any other integer you specify in your own version), it can not handle arbitrary-length lists. You will probably need your own print function for that case.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this and wanted to write one ugly one-liner, so here it is:

```
>>> l = range(25)
>>> w = 5
>>> print '\n'.join([str(x) for x in [l[i:i + w] for i in range(0, 25, w)]])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Take it just as an idea

Answer (score -1):

Here's one of you:

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if i != 0 and i % (len(myList)/numOfLines) == 0: 
        print '\n'
    print myList[i],
```

Comment: This does not print the leading [ nor trailing ], nor does it indent the all of the lines except the first.